# Design Pattern for constructing an object which requires data from multiple UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns

In this question I want to discuss how to construct an object which requires data from multiple `UIViewControllers` which are embedded in an `UINavigationController`.

For this post I'm providing an example where I'm making a demo-app where users can buy fake plane-tickets. This is the oversimplified struct that represents a `Ticket`:

```
struct Ticket {

    let originAirport: Airport // UIViewController 1 provides this data.
    let destinationAirport: Airport // UIViewController 1 provides this data.

    let departDate: Date // UIViewController 2 provides this data.
    let returnDate: Date // UIViewController 2 provides this data.

    let customerName: String // UIViewController 3 provides this data.
}
```

The process of booking a `Ticket` requires multiple steps / `UIViewControllers`. In every `UIViewController` I can get some - but not all data about the ticket. At the end of all steps I want a Ticket struct/object which has all the data in it's properties. **What is a nice design pattern to handle this problem?**

These are a few "solutions" I considered:

1. Passing data through segues: For every step / `UIViewController` I'd pass on a partly constructed `Ticket` object to the next `UIViewController`. This new `UIViewController` adds additional information to the object. The problem with this approach is that for every `UIViewController` I need to pass a `Ticket` object with partly filled in information. This means that the properties in `Ticket` are *optional* .. which doesn't make sense from the `Ticket` perspective: all properties are required. The other problem is that the `UIViewControllers` are tightly coupled with each other and this problem becomes bigger once the amount of steps increase.
2. Use a Singleton / UserDefaults: This is a hack-ish workaround
   which isn't a solution to the problem.

Perhaps I'm dealing with an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) - maybe my solution doesn't make sense where I'm initialising the Ticket object once all steps are finished. But what would be a good approach to solve this problem?

Comment: I would highly recommend to avoid the second solution "Use a Singleton / UserDefaults".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is called `Builder Pattern`. You can read a short explanation [here](https://medium.com/swift-programming/the-builder-pattern-in-swift-770d9cc1ac41).

More detailed explanation is:

1. You may create `class TicketBuilder`. Why class? Well, classes are passed by reference, while structs are passed by value.
2. In every VC in the reservation process, you may have shared field "var ticket: TicketBuilder" as you have described in your question, passed by `prepareForSegue` method. The difference is that it all will be referenced to the first creation of the `TicketBuilder` instance(in the first VC - no unnecessary memory allocation YEY!).
3. What is more, as an implementation suggestion of the Builder Pattern, several things are important: `var isBuild: Bool` bool property, `.canBuild()->Bool` verification method and `.build()->Ticket` method that creates actual Ticket from TicketBuilder class.

Lastly, on my opinion, having Singleton Manager class for such a long reservation flow is pretty good solution, and I won't mind using it.

Comment: `In every VC in the reservation process, you may have shared field "ticket"` This is a singleton, and he clearly said he wanted to avoid that. Singletons are rarely good and mostly causes memory leaks and bugs.

Comment: @Vollan No, and no...  Each VC in the Reservation Flow may have `var ticket: TicketBuilder` and this will be passed in `prepareForSegue` method, thus not singleton. And about "Singletons ... causes memory leaks and bugs", badly written code in general does this, not the Singleton pattern. For instance, for singletons it is good practice to define `clearData()` method that handles memory after some functionality is done.

Comment: But dependency injection beats singleton in every single case. As it stop appearing when you stop using it.

https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/avoiding-singletons-in-swift

Comment: @Vollan this is a matter of another discussion, friend :) I am not arguing that Singletons are better or something like that, I have just expressed my opinion that this pattern is pretty helpful for implementing long stories/user flows :)

Comment: @Vollan, as dvp.petrov says, this is not a singleton pattern.  There can clearly be more than one instance of a `TicketBuilder` during the lifetime of the app.  One of the main objections to singleton is the impact on testability.  A singleton, almost by definition, cannot cause memory leaks since the lifetime of the object is the lifetime of the app and there can only be one instance.  Having said all of that, I would pass the `TicketBuilder` instance between view controllers and not use a singleton in this case.

Comment: This makes sense, I didn't know about this pattern and it seems to do the trick - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The best solution for this, if you are saying that you that you go step by step is using `dependency injection`
This explains pretty good why you should avoid singletons and how `dependency injection` solves your problem

https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/avoiding-singletons-in-swift

Your first solution suggest this, but you don't necessarily need to send a Ticket object as a injection, you can send the different variables as a `dictionary` and at the last step transform the `dictionary` to an `Ticket object`